# ¿Cómo hago un evento que incremente toda una columna progresivamente en mysql?

Tags: mysql

He escrito este código:

```
CREATE EVENT PruebaCalculoBateria 

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND 

DO 

UPDATE bateria SET Bateria = Bateria + Disponible
```

Los valores de la tabla llegan desde otra mediante un trigger.
No me da ningún error, pero yo quiero que modifique la *bateria* de toda la columna;
solo se modifica el primer valor que llega a la tabla *bateria*.

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con esto: *pero yo quiero que modifique la bateria de toda la columna, solo se modifica el primer valor que llega a la tabla bateria*. Por favor, sé más claro en el planteamiento y si es posible pon algún ejemplo basado en datos.